# Casting complex values discards imaginary part on fast fourier algorithm

Tags: python, fft

I was making the fast fourier transformation algorithm, based on cooley-tukey method. The code looks fine to me, but I keep getting numpy error like:

```
Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

I am not sure how to change the assignments in the iterrations. The algorithm is described here:

```py
def fast_fourier_transformation(data):
    N = len(data)
    if N > 1:
        Wn = math.e ** (2 * math.pi * 1j / N)
        W = 1
        A_even = data[::2]
        A_odd = data[1::2]
        B_even = fast_fourier_transformation(A_even)
        B_odd = fast_fourier_transformation(A_odd)
        for k in range(0, N // 2):
            data[k] = B_even[k] + W * B_odd[k]
            data[k + N // 2] = B_even[k] - W * B_odd[k]
            W = W * Wn
    return data
```

Comment: On this one: data[k] = B_even[k] + W * B_odd[k]

Comment: My data array is float numbers and the expected result is complex numbers

Comment: Fourier Transforms are inherently complex so you should be passing in a complex data array.

Comment: Try to define`B_even` as complex,  `np.array(B_even, dtype=complex)`. And the same for `W`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog tell me how you get complex numbers from .wav file.

Comment: @yatu it doesn't help

Comment: Use the values as the real component and set the imaginary component to zero. You shouldn't discard the imaginary component either, because the *meaningful* information about the waveform is contained in the **polar representation** (amplitude + phase) of the output.

Comment: Well at some point as the error suggests it is casting some complex valued array to real, which suggests that there is some operation involving mixed types

Comment: @meowgoesthedog this doesn't look ok: [ 6.+0.j -2.+2.j  6.+0.j -2.-2.j]. For the dataset of [ 2.  1.  4. -1.] I should get: [(1.5+0j), (-0.49999999999999994-0.5000000000000001j), (1.5+3.0616169978683826e-16j), (-0.5000000000000001+0.49999999999999967j)]

Comment: Remember to **normalize** the output (divide by either `N` or `sqrt(N)` depending on the mathematical convention). You should probably read a Fourier Transforms theory tutorial before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Your data variable needs to be declared as complex (set the imaginary component to zero for strictly real input), since the output of your function needs to be complex, and you are using "data" for both the input parameter and the return value (output).